# How does rethrowing an exception from a "catch all" block generate the same exception in C++?

Tags: c++, exception

```
#include<iostream>
#include<exception>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try{
        try{
            throw 20;
        }catch(...)
        {
            cout<<"Unknown exception in inner block"<<endl;
            throw;
        }
    }catch(int e)
    {
        cout<<"Integer Exception "<<e<<endl;
    }catch(...)
    {
        cout<<"Unknown exception in outer block"<<endl;
    }
}
```

The above code gives the output:

```
Unknown exception in inner block    
Integer Exception 20
```

I read in an answer that it is not possible to determine the exception in a catch all block.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence. You read correctly, there is no portable way for the programmer to determine it. It doesn't mean the C++ implementation and run-time can't do it in order to match handlers. They have inside knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `throw;`, the C++ compiler rethrows the caught exception *by reference*.

It's almost as if the `catch (...)` was not there, barring the intercepting `std::cout` statement.

So it's re-caught at the `int e` catch site.

C++11 goes some way in allowing you to capture the exception in a catch block, *including* `catch (...)`, but there is no portable way of inspecting the exception caught in a `catch (...)` block. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception.

Answer (score 1):

Rethrowing exception does not generate new exception object. Instead it continues throwing the same exception object.

> **18.1 Throwing an exception [except.throw]**
>
> 4. ... If a handler exits by rethrowing, control is passed to another handler for the same exception object.

Comment: So, how can we access that exception object ?
I mean if an int is sent as an exception, it is not possible to call exception object methods on it like std::exception::what(). How would I know it's value then ?

Comment: @HrikshitRajChauhan Access to exception object is performed by writing catch clause with appropriate type, such as `catch(int const & e)`.